# Перемещение по перевернутой карте

Tags: android, java

Вопрос состоит вот в чем, когда я переворачиваю карту и начинаю её перемещать пальцем у меня создается инверсия карты, для того что бы этого небыло я создал функцию которая перехватывает координаты пальца и обрабатывает через синусы и косинусы так что бы инверсии не было. Но проблема возникла такая что точка от которой отталкивается постоянно палец является одна и та же, то есть я как не листаю карту она все время возвращается в одно и то же место, что вверх что вниз что вправо что влево. Вот мой код который обрабатывает координаты пальца:

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        float lastX = 0.0f;
        float lastY = 0.0f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            int deltaX = (int) (lastX - x);
            int deltaY = (int) (lastY - y);
            mc.scrollBy(
                    (int) ((deltaX * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle))) + (deltaY * Math
                            .sin(-Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle)))), (int) ((deltaX * Math
                            .sin(Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle))) + (deltaY * Math.cos(-Math
                            .toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle)))));
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                x += Math.cos(-Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle));
                y += Math.sin(-Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle));
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Если я правильно понял - при простом нажатии на тач карта следует за пальцем.
  В коде не обрабатывается событие ACTION_DOWN, при котором нужно записать в `lastX` и `lastY` текущие координаты и не скроллить карту.
- К тому же обработка ACTION_MOVE не имеет эффекта.

> ```
> if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
> x += Math.cos(-Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle));
> y += Math.sin(-Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle));
> }
> ```

- Лучше один раз вычислить sin и cos, и правильно вынести знаки.

**UPD**
Как вариант:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
      int deltaX = (int) (lastX - x);
      int deltaY = (int) (lastY - y);
      float a=Math.toRadians(mRotateView.rotateAngle);
      float cos=Math.cos(a),sin=Math.sin(a);
      mc.scrollBy((int) (deltaX * cos - deltaY * sin), (int) (deltaX * sin + deltaY * cos));
    }
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: что предлагаете? засунуть конструкцию в ACTION_DOWN ?

Comment: только `lastX = x;lastY = y;`

Comment: спасибо) то что нужно!